# setByAddingObject on CoreData NSManagedObject relationship doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

I'm currently trying to update my code so it's more efficient, to do this I am looking at the update function of my CoreData managed objects. I have the following code which works correctly, however, the Time Profiler within instruments shows the creation of relationships is fairly slow. Both objects have a one to many relationship, therefore have sets which I update as follows:

```
NSMutableSet *labelSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:labelEntity.rTickets];
if (![labelSet containsObject:entity])
{
    [labelSet addObject:entity];
    [labelEntity setRTickets:labelSet];
}

NSMutableSet *ticketSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:[(TicketEntity *)entity rLabels]];
if (![ticketSet containsObject:labelEntity])
{
    [ticketSet addObject:labelEntity];
    [(TicketEntity *)entity setRLabels:ticketSet];
}
```

This all works as expected, all the CoreData persists correctly and the data is displayed in my `UITableView` in another class. However, I feel the same should be achievable using the more concise code below:

```
if (![labelEntity.rTickets containsObject:entity])
     [labelEntity.rTickets setByAddingObject:entity];

if (![[(TicketEntity *)entity rLabels] containsObject:labelEntity])
     [[(TicketEntity *)entity rLabels] setByAddingObject:labelEntity];
```

For some reason this does not act as expected, none of the entities relationships are kept persistent. Am I missing something obviously different with this function? At first I thought perhaps the set wasn't initialised correctly, therefore `setByAddingObject` was being called on a nil set, so I tried initialising the set first and all subsequent requests used `setByAddingObject` but this made no difference. Can anyone let me know why the second code above doesn't work? Or the best way to manage relationships between two multi `NSManagedObjects`.

Thanks

Comment: The method `setByAddingObject` returns a set, which you are ignoring.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks for the help. I presumed it applied it to the set it was called on, thanks!

Comment: If those two relationships are inverse to one another, you don't need to set both: CoreData will automatically update the inverse relationship for you.  Also, habe you tried using `mutableSetValueForKey:` to see whether it is any quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will remove the inverse relationships. I haven't tried a mutableSet for these, will it make a notable difference do you reckon, if so I will switch it?